# Looking for explanation about specifc nodes of config.xml

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am preparing for the certification and i have doubts about specific nodes of config.xml like < customer>, < sales>, < payment>, etc… And another doubt is about the custom nodes in the < default> node various modules uses like the one following:

```
<default>
    <monkey>
    <custom_groupings>
        <customer_grouping_name><![CDATA[MAGE_CUSTOMER_GROUPS]]>      
    </customer_grouping_name>
    <segment_grouping_name><![CDATA[MAGE_CUSTOMER_SEGMENTS]]></segment_grouping_name>
    </custom_groupings>
        <general>
            <active>0</active>
            <double_optin>System->Configuration->Customers->Newsletter->
 SubscriptionOptions->Need to Confirm</double_optin>
            <ecommerce360>0</ecommerce360>
            <checkout_subscribe>0</checkout_subscribe>
            <transactional_emails>false</transactional_emails>

        </general>
    </monkey>
</default>
```

Comment: Custom modules can add whatever nodes they like into the xml config, it's just a configuration tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Config XML just needs to have valid syntax. Whether the structure/content affects the application is a function of module design. Therefore, the best question to ask is, "what information and techniques are available for gaining insight into Magento's config XML?"

There are several resources online with varying levels of quality and accuracy. For the specialized resources, I'd recommend looking for any class definition file named `Config.php`. For example, the content of the [`Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Config` [link]](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.5.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Config.php) introduces the application's use of the `global/sales/order` xpath, for example.

To build an exhaustive list, grep the source for the following text:

- getStoreConfig
- getConfig
- *.xml

Good luck. Remember that current version of the MCD exam (a/o Dec 2012) is based on CE 1.5.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I was a bit frustrated about explanation on these items as i didnt find any good material... But your explanation elucidated me... Thx a lot

Comment: What about the nodes under:

    <global>
        <fieldsets>
             ...
?

Comment: Re `global/fieldsets`: see [`Mage_Core_Helper_Data::copyFieldset()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.5.1.0/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php#L385)

Comment: Thanks for the fast replay but the last i didnt get it, looked the method but still catn figure out how Magento uses theses nodes, and the * generally used in it... I get this code:  

Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('customer_account', 'to_quote', $customer, $this);

In app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php, but dont figure out where this configuration is set, tried config.xml frmo both mage/Sales and Mage/Customer modules but no success...

Comment: `grep -srl 'copyFieldset' ./app/code/core/`

Comment: I did it but was slow to figure out what it was supposed to do... It just copy one object into another, in the case customer_account, to_quote it copy customer object to quote... Thanks Benmarks